# How do I find the unknown program enabled during Start-Up?

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager, autostart

I am using a computer with Windows 10 and, as a normal procedure to reduce the boot time, I accessed the Task Manager and checked what was "Enabled" during the "Start-up".

[image: Some of the programs]

When I opened that tab, I saw a program called "Program", without Publisher information, which I have now disabled.

[image: Program Disabled it]

After that, I went straight to the Control Panel -> Programs and Features, in order to find out what the program is and to delete it; however, nothing with that name appears.

Given that, assuming that I don't know since when do I have that program on this computer, how can I know what this program is, so that I can decide on whether to remove it or not?

Comment: You can also display more columns in Task Manager, by the way, including “Startup type” and “Command line”. Just right-click any column header.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can go to Microsoft Downloads, SysInternals and get Autoruns 64-bit ([download it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)). Download it, install it and run it and see if it shows you the program on your computer.

For your specific problem, access the "Logon" Tab.

[image: Autoruns Logon]

Yellow highlighted sections in the Autoruns display are errors and can be deleted.

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 31):

You can rightclick on an entry and click `Open file location` wich leads you to the directory where the program is installed.

[image: Open file location]

As mentioned in the comments by Ismael Miguel this answer only applies to Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 (and the Windows Server variants). For Windows 7 and older, you need to use msconfig.

Comment: This answer only applies to Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 (and the Windows Server variants). For Windows 7 and older, you need to use `msconfig`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel OP clearly specified he uses Windows 10

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă That's true, but someone who searches for an answer to this question, on older devices, will find that it doesn't work for them. Besides, it is just a sentence that was added, and only increases the value of the answer, without making it invalid for what the O.P. asked.

Comment: "This answer only applies to Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 (and the Windows Server variants)."  Autoruns works just fine in Windows 7 and shows the Yellow entries to delete just fine

Comment: @John ye the thing with autorun imho is that you have to download a tool.

Comment: Of course you need to download Autoruns from Systinternals (Microsoft) but once downloaded and installed it works fine

Comment: This didn't work in this particular, as the "Open file location" was blocked (one couldn't press it). It just happened to me again.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 Yes it can be. Go with [Johns](https://superuser.com/a/1499240/848584) answer then.

Answer (score 10):

Start-up entries are in the registry at [`Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys), and `Software\WOW6432Node\...` for 32-bit programs. There is one of these keys for each user and machine. For the current session that would be under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Any shortcuts in a Start Menu group called Startup (`Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`) will also be run. Again there are both per-user and per-machine locations, under `%AllUsersProfile%` and `%AppData%` for the current session.

Additionally, a scheduled task can be set to run at boot or login. This data is also in the registry `Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule`, but in a much more complex format. This can be explored with the "Task Scheduler" app.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, there's also the magic Start Menu folder in addition to the registry.

Comment: @IMSoP Actually there's a lot of ways to make something start with the system. For example you can schedule a task that executes on logon. *Autoruns* is great at finding these.

Comment: @IMSoP I think it is _in this case_. We have a screenshot from Task Manager, so it must be in the registry.

Comment: @gronostaj I just checked Task Manager on my system, and the programs I load through the Start Menu folder show up there. I've no idea what other areas it includes, but it's certainly more than just that one set of registry entries.