# Windows 10 - Disable UWP process group apps from running automatically

Tags: windows-10, process, task-manager, tasks, autorun

Edition: **Windows 10 Home** | Version: **1909** | OS build: **18363.693**.

---

Just came across a specific process group on Windows 10, in the `Task Manager`.

It is known as **UWP** and represented with a leaf, as one can see in the image bellow:

[image: UWP process group]

> This UWP process group is suspending processes to improve system
>   performance.

I have decided to look through all the `Background Processes` and find which ones were linked with this process group.

Let's look at the apps linked with this process and see its response when one tries to End Task.

---

**1) Cortana**

Even though Cortana is suspended on my machine, it is still running in the background:

[image: UWP - Cortana]

I selected the process and pressed "End Task", however, without waiting more than 2 seconds, a new process emerges:

[image: Cortana appearing again]

Then it appears a Background Task Host:

[image: Cortana - New Background Task Host]

Which turns into Cortana Background Task Host:

[image: Cortana - Background Task Host]

Till eventually ends up like this:

[image: Cortana]

How can one disable Cortana completely? (I have come across [questions like this one](https://superuser.com/questions/949569/can-i-completely-disable-cortana-on-windows-10), however they seem out of date as they don't consider the **UWP process group**)

---

**2) Photos**

The Photos is also part of the UWP process group:

[image: Photos - UWP process group]

But when ending the task it didn't pop up again, nor even after a period of 20min waiting.

---

**3) Settings**

Settings is also part of this process group:

[image: Settings - UWP process group]

But, as Photos, when ending the task it didn't pop up again, nor even after a period of 20min waiting.

---

**4) Skype**

Even though Skype is Disabled during the start-up

[image: Skype disabled during start-up]

It still manages to run without personally executing it - and it is also part of the UWP group.

[image: Skype UWP gorup]

After ending the task it didn't start immediately, but during the waiting period of 20min, the process started to run:

[image: Skype - Running again]

Till eventually becoming the following:
[image: Skype - UWP as the beginning]

---

**5) Your Phone**

[Your Phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hub/4529948/your-phone-app-help), is also running and it is part of the UWP process group:

[image: Your Phone - UWP process group]

But when ending the task it didn't pop up again, nor even after a period of 20min waiting.

---

As one could see from what I mentioned above, some apps are now running in the background without one open them up, and even if they are disabled during Start-up ([check my question for answers on controlling start-up tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/1499188/how-do-i-find-the-unknown-program-enabled-during-start-up)).

Even though that is happening, one is able to close most of the tasks belonging to the UWP process group. However, one is not able to end Cortana nor Skype.

**How does one fully disable UWP process group tasks from running automatically, more specifically Cortana and Skype, even after one closes them?**

Comment: UWP is an application you installed - it is not part of native Windows 10. Uninstall UWP.  Restart when that has been uninstalled. You may need to run DISM and SFC to correct issues.

Comment: Also, using third party apps to stop embedded processes from running is not a good idea. What you wish to stop above does not cause any issue in normal operation.

Comment: In the case of Cortana you have to uninstall it to prevent it from running.  This might change in a future version of Windows 10.  UWP applications must be programmed to support what you want.  This is the reason some UWP applications behave differently.

Comment: Sorry to bump such an old post, but I'd like to know the answer to it as well.

Comment: @John I don't remember installing it. In the Control Panel can't seem to find `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)` nor any of the apps, such as YourPhone ([that is still running](https://imgur.com/7QbB1X7)). Can't find them in Microsoft Store either. And in the Settings>Apps, the Uninstall button is not active ([as one can see here](https://imgur.com/SE7fQLu)).

Answer (score 3):

To disable globally or for individual apps, i.e. to prevent "UWP Apps" from running on their own in background:

Go to "Settings -> Privacy -> Background Apps (scroll down to it) ...

From there you can disable each app individually with the toggle beside the app name, or you can flip the top-most toggle, "Let Apps run in the background", to OFF to globally disable.  With this set to OFF, none of those apps should run or be launched for the stated "UWP" reasons of maintaining their versioning and etc..

So disable individually or via the top-most toggle - to OFF.  Again, that is:

```
Settings -> Privacy -> Background Apps then toggle to OFF for specific apps or turn "Let Apps run in the background" to OFF.
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem.
For example, the Background Apps toggles, including `Let apps run in the background` are turned off, but the app "Your Phone" still appears in the task manager as an UWP App: [as this](https://imgur.com/7QbB1X7).